# Continue Execution After HttpResponse Django

Tags: django

I want am working with a webhook that times out .

To acknowledge receipt I have to send a 200 ok response .
Then continue my execution.
Code looks something like this

```
def webhook(request):
   return HttpResponse(status=200)
   print(“ok”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before return, then u can't print("ok"). You can just write something before returning it